# SuperImpose one cv::mat image over another

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv-mat

I am working on a source code that will help me to superimpose a `cv::Mat` image  of a skeletal stream (obtained from a Kinect ) with another `cv::Mat` image which is a normal camera color (BGR) image.

The code looks like this

```
cv::Mat imageMixer(cv::Mat colorImage,cv::Mat skeletalImage)
{
  // code to superimpose the skeletal image ... opencv function
  cv::Mat resultantImage = colorImage + skeletalImage;
  return resultantImage;
}
```

How can we superimpose a `cv::Mat` image on top of another `cv::Mat` based image ? Is there a OpenCV function that we can directly make use of ?

Comment: Have a look at `addWeighted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV Documentation has a good tutorial for exactly what you are asking, check out [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) link.